# Printing on a legacy DOS program hosted on a VM

Tags: aes, virtual, dos, rdp, printers

I work in a high school IT office.  From the 90s through 2002, we used a DOS program called AES to manage electronic student records (grades, attendance, transcripts).  We moved the application over to a virtual server about 12 years ago when we decommissioned its server.

I have worked here for 5 years and this is the first time that a student from that era has requested a transcript and we don't have the paper copy.  So... I muddled my way through the menus and figured out how to print the transcript.  But the application requires a printer attached to actually print the transcript.  It errors out and hangs without a printer.  We have a printer attached through RDP, which works for native Windows apps, but not this system.

Is there a way to fake the DOS application to see the RDP printer as LPT1?

Comment: You might have better luck asking on [SE's superuser](https://superuser.com). Some quick googling shows the following results - [1](https://superuser.com/q/1065746), [2](https://www.dosprint.com/), [3](https://dosprinter.net/). Good luck!

Comment: You can add a virtual serial or parallel port to the virtual machine and redirect it to a file on your host. ("Virtual Machine Settings" - "Add..." "Parallel Port" (or serial) - "use output file") (hoping the program writes plain text) You then can print the file from your host system (or just email it to the student - "save the trees")

Comment: Unfortunately it's on a very old virtual server and we haven't had any luck with generating PDFs on this machine.  The system was VERY insistent on LPT1 only there was no other setup options.

Answer (score 3):

So here's how I fixed it...

1. shared the printer on the VM
2. edited the batch file that launched the DOS application to have these commands:

```
net use lpt1 \\vmname\printername
```

3. Rebooted
4. Went into the application's (minimal) printer setup area and was able to get it to send a test page

Only after those specific steps would the student files print out.